# iOS Share Extension not working after deploy

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-share-extension

I have created a Share extension which working fine while I am running it though xcode on device or simulator. But when I creating IPA or using TestFlight, it is not passing my list from host app to extension.

I am creating this extension for posting an image in host app ( without uploading on server just in local sqlite ). For this I have checked, App Group and it is fine, cross checked the provisioning certificate and it is also attached with app group.

If you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: If you are passing data then you must be using an app group, have you checked app groups is enabled for distribution as well as for development.

Comment: yes app group enabled,

Comment: Even here I am not using distribution settings, the same setting by which I am running the app XCode to Device ( development ), I am creating the iPA ( with same development settings ). That also not showing the list in extension

Comment: Then if its debug build, put logging in and try to figure out what's going wrong. I can't think of any reason running via Xcode would work but not via ipa.

Comment: yes, Same I added some logs its just display Null with that content and before that following error I am getting following message


nsuserdefaults <Error>: Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x17411c290>

Comment: I am getting following error code <Error>: Failed to read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x17011cc20> (Domain: group.com.*****.******, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes, Container: (null)): Using kCFPreferencesAnyUser with a container is only allowed for System Containers, detaching from cfprefsd code @Alfonsod'Arsebiscuit

Comment: That message is not the problem. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51348

Comment: @Kapil You find any solution I getting the same issue

Answer (score 2):

The entitlement file needs to have the group id information and same should be reflected in build settings.

For me it was just that entitlement file was missing from build settings under code signing entitlements for release.

In debug the app does not require entitlement file.